How are we passing context while creating endpoint in go-kit
func MakeGetEndpoint(srv Service) endpoint.Endpoint {
    return func(ctx context.Context, request interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        _ = request.(getRequest) // we really just need the request, we don't use any value from it
        d, err := srv.Get(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            return getResponse{d, err.Error()}, nil
        }
        return getResponse{d, ""}, nil
    }
}

    // mapping endpoints
    endpoints := napodate.Endpoints{
        GetEndpoint:      napodate.MakeGetEndpoint(srv)
    }

func (e Endpoints) Get(ctx context.Context) (string, error) {
    req := getRequest{}
    resp, err := e.GetEndpoint(ctx, req)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    getResp := resp.(getResponse)
    if getResp.Err != "" {
        return "", errors.New(getResp.Err)
    }
    return getResp.Date, nil
}

How are we ensuring the ctx used during e.GetEndpoint(ctx, req) is the same ctx that is used in MakeEndpoint. Also, when is MakeEndpoint getting actually executed and how it gets access to srv, ctx and request.

You don't, actually they are expected to be different.
A Go kit endpoint “represents a single RPC method”. When executed, it is executed in the context of the individual request. Then means when an individual request is canceled (for example due to a time out), that individual execution context is canceled. Also, this context carries authorization, tracing and other request relevant information.
The endpoint is created in the program initialization context. This is different from the request execution, carries other information and is probably only canceled when initialization fails.
ctx and request are parameters of your endpoint function and are different for every request. srv is captured in the function literal from what you passed to MakeGetEndpoint, so it stays the same for all requests.
